# Gorm tags for compound unique key

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

How to describe gorm tags for a compound UNIQUE key?

Postgres:

```
phone_country_code VARCHAR(10), 
phone_number VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT phone_country_code_number UNIQUE (phone_country_code, phone_number)
```

Go (fields of model struct):

```
PhoneCountryCode       string    `gorm:"column:phone_country_code; type:VARCHAR(10)"`
PhoneNumber            string    `gorm:"column:phone_number; type:VARCHAR(25)"`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs on Composite Indexes](https://gorm.io/docs/indexes.html#Composite-Indexes) you can create a unique composite index by using the same index name in two or more fields:

```golang
PhoneCountryCode       string    `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_code_phone; type:VARCHAR(10)"`
PhoneNumber            string    `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_code_phone; type:VARCHAR(25)"`
```

This will have the same effect as adding a constraint.

(Note: I removed the `column` tag for legibility, it's not needed as gorm snake cases the field names to get column names by default).

Comment: This still creates an "index" and not a constraint, giving you less control if you want to have fewer indexes or want "INSERT ... ON CONSTRAINT (constraint_name)" afterward.